# How to subtract time from NSDate with the help of NSDateFormatter?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm working on an application in which user set a time to do a task and before 10 or 15 minutes application triggers an alarm. Just like a reminder app you can say.

After searching a lot on stackOverFlow and other different links my problem still exists. Here is what I'm doing:

```
-(void)timeWasSelected:(NSDate *)selectedTime element:(id)element {

    if((UITextField *)element == self.timeForTask){
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
        self.textField.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:selectedTime];
        [defaults setObject:self.textField.text forKey:@"taskTime"];
        myTime = [selectedTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:-600];
        NSLog(@"New Time %@",myTime);
    }
```

After doing this the NSLog part gives this output: `New Time 2015-04-27 06:14:14 +0000`

The problem is that I've selected time `11:22AM` and it is storing `06:14` and I've only deducted `10min` from the selected time.

Comment: This time is in GMT. You are getting proper time.

Comment: "I've only deducted 10sec from the selected time."
I think you are subtracting -600 seconds which is 10 minutes.

Comment: in simulator the time is always display 5 hour 30 min less but when you check it with breakpoint it display proper time you have selected for proper time you have to set time zone

Comment: You can use Calendar for setting alarm like reminder app before 10 or 15 min of the event..! R u using Calendar for Storing the events..!I have done this using Calendars...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this you will get output:

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
    NSDate* selectedTime = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"11:22 AM"];
   NSDate* myTime = [selectedTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*10];//10 minute deduction
    NSString* updateTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myTime];
    NSLog(@"New Time %@",updateTime);
```

Output :

**New Time 11:12 AM**

Here you are subtracting 10 Minutes from selected time. if you want 15 Minutes then replace with 10 digits.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

// gives new date object with time 15 minutes earlier

```
 NSDate *newDate = [oldDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*15]; 
   NSString* NewTime = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:newDate];
    NSLog(@"New Time %@",newDate);
```

This code will exactly get you 15 minutes earlier time

Answer (score 0):

Try this, may help you,

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
NSLog(@"1New Time %@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:selectedTime]);
self.textField.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:selectedTime];
[defaults setObject:self.textField.text forKey:@"taskTime"];
NSTimeZone *destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:destinationTimeZone];
NSDate *myTime = [selectedTime dateByAddingTimeInterval:-600];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter1 setTimeZone:destinationTimeZone];
[dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss ZZ"];
NSLog(@"2New Time %@",[dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:myTime]);
```

Enjoy Coding !!